# low level socket connection to MySQL database Python

Tags: python

Hello I would like to ask:

How can I make a socket connection to a MySQL database (With out additional libraries) using only low level sockets so I can then send commands.

Thank you for any help

Edit is it also possible to connect over HTTP? (I wouldn't think that would make sense, but figured I would ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible, you'll 'only' have to implement the [MySQL Client/Server Protocol](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html).

If you want to have a look at how this can be done (or if it's too much work to do it yourself), have a look at [pymysql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) or [myconnpy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysql-connector-python).